# which of these files is the stock recovery image for the nexus 4 android 4.3?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

which of these files is the stock recovery image for the nexus 4 android 4.3?

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/occam-jwr66y-factory-74b1deab.tgz

Is it

[image]

Or is it

[image]

So, is it bootloader-mako-makoz20i.img  or boot.img or recovery.img?

And what are the differences between these?

I will be doing `fastboot flash recovery blah.img`  I can guess that recovery.ing is the correct one. But I want to verify here and also it makes me wonder though what the other two are for and what command would replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for `recovery.img`. Extra info below:

`bootloader-mako-xxx.img` -> bootloader. Flash with `fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-mako-xxx.img` then `fastboot reboot-bootloader`. Updates (upgrade or downgrade) bootloader for compatibility with corresponding generation of ROMs.

`boot.img` -> kernel. Flash with `fastboot flash boot boot.img` or boot once with `fastboot boot boot.img`. Only use original ones or ones that are known compatible.